# Resize external command line window

Tags: winapi

What is better way to change size of command line windows in next case:

1. I started cmd process from my application
2. I set my widget as parent of cmd window

Now I need to resize command line window after widget resize event. But I have maximal size setted within my application.

Most examples used `hStdOut` of console, but how can (if can) I get it by cmd process id/window handle (now I haven't any other data)?

Also, sending of `mode` command in window is unsuitable - user can start any programm in command line window (e.g. run `ssh` client), so I can not be sure that command really will started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's an overkill, but why not to inject DLL which will use standard API to resize process console? If you started the process as you stated, you have process handle, so you can [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx) and then [Inject DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) which will call [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125.aspx) from it's DllMain. DLL can be very tiny, 1Kb or so without CRT.

Comment: Calling `WaitForInputIdle` for a process that doesn't implement a message loop is meaningless. The command processor does not implement a message loop. The API was invented to address DDE's reliance on broadcasts to establish the initial conversation.

Comment: From MSDN:  "For example, the parent process should use the WaitForInputIdle function before trying to find a window associated with the child process"

Comment: Exactly: *"[...] a **window** associated with the child process"*. The command processor does not have windows associated with it. As I stated previously, the API is intended to be used with DDE, to find the right time to broadcast **messages**.

Comment: This is actually implementation detail. I know that csrss.exe actually owns all console windows, but why not to call one extra function and be sure nothing breaks in future OS versions?

Comment: It is broken in current OS versions already. There is **nothing** to be gained from calling `WaitForInputIdle` on a command processor process. The call is **meaningless** for non-GUI processes. And even for GUI processes, it doesn't do what its name implies.

Comment: OK, I understand you.

Comment: I solved problem by making custom command-line application that start "cmd.exe" in one thread and getted messages about size by other thread (yes, maybe it's not better way)